# checkbox android sequence logic

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I have 6 checkboxs, only the first one will be clickable.. after the first one is checked, then allow the 2nd.. when the 2nd is checked, then allow the 3rd.. the checked checkboxs also need to be disabled to avoid the user uncheck them..

I think I need to use array? can't figure out how is the logic..

```
if(checkbox1.isChecked()){
            checkbox1.setEnabled(false);
        }else if(checkbox2.isChecked()){
            checkbox2.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

this won't work..

Comment: try with flag variable when user checked checkboxes assign value to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a listener for the checkboxes and enable the next one whenever the previous one is clicked.

Example:

```
CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked){
            cb1.setEnabled(false);
            cb2.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }         
});
```

Comment: I need to set for all of those cb? I implements onCheckedChangeListener, is that the reason why it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, you would set a listener for each checkbox. Each one (except for the very last one) would set itself as disabled and the next one as enabled. The last one would just set itself as disabled, since there is no next one. 
It shouldn't matter if you implement it or not, if you use the above code it should work. (If you already are setting checkedChangeListeners for your boxes, just add the above code to the existing listeners. )